# change 2d array values wave like

Tags: c#, arrays, algorithm

I have a two-dimensional array, each cell stores a value. At some point, the value of some cell changes. Let's call that cell Original. I want the values of all neighboring cells to change, say, to add some small value. I did it, but what to do with the neighbors of the neighbors? I wrote this method, but for some reason the result looks irregulary. It would be great if you could help me or at least tell me what to google because I can't find anything useful.

My method:

```
public void UpdateNearbyPrices(
    ProductType productType, Cell[,] cells, int depth, List<Cell> updated)
{
    if (depth == 0) return;
    var neighbours = GetNeighbours(cells);
    var deltaPrice = depth * 0.10f;
    foreach (Cell n in neighbours)
    {
        if (updated.Contains(n)) continue;
        n.GetProduct(productType).Price += deltaPrice;
        updated.Add(n);
    }

    foreach (Cell n in neighbours)
    {
        n.UpdateNearbyPrices(productType, cells, depth - 1, updated);
    }
}
```

Cell is a class that stores list of products. Let's say it has only one product and value is the product's price. I display prices on grid.
I call it from cell class like this:

```
List<Cell> updated = new List<Cell>();
updated.Add(this);
var depth = (int)(product.Price / 10) - 1;
UpdateNearbyPrices(productType, cells, Mathf.Min(depth, 5), updated);
```

When I run the app I add some value to product's price, expecting to see more or less stone-thrown-into-a-puddle-like behaviour, but I see this:
[mypicture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x9Nhc.png). The greenest cell is the Original cell. This project is made in Godot.

Minimal reproductive console app:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace UpdateNearbyPrices
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int rows = 10; int cols = 10;
            Cell[,] cells = new Cell[rows, cols];

            for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++)
            {
                var cell = new Cell 
                { 
                    Id = i.ToString() + '_' + j.ToString(),
                    ProductList = new List<Product> { new Product() }
                };
                cells[i, j] = cell;
            }

            while(true)
            {
                cells[5, 5].SetNewPrice(ProductType.Lumber, cells);
                Console.Clear();
                Print(cells);
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }

        public static void Print(Cell[,] cells)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < cells.GetLength(0); i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < cells.GetLength(1); j++)
                {
                    float value = cells[i, j].GetProduct(ProductType.Lumber).Price;
                    Console.Write(value.ToString("000.00") + "|");
                }

                Console.WriteLine("\n----------------------------------------------------------------------");
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Press Enter to 0.5f to cell[5, 5].");
        }
    }

    public class Cell
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public List<Product> ProductList { get; set; }

        public Product GetProduct(ProductType type) => ProductList.First(p => p.ProductType == type);

        internal void SetNewPrice(ProductType productType, Cell[,] cells)
        {
            Product product = GetProduct(productType);
            product.Price += 0.5f;

            //change neighbours prices
            List<Cell> updated = new List<Cell>();
            updated.Add(this);
            var depth = (int)(product.Price / 10) - 1;
            UpdateNearbyPrices(productType, cells, Math.Min(depth, 5), updated); 
        }

        public void UpdateNearbyPrices(
            ProductType productType, Cell[,] cells, int depth, List<Cell> updated)
        {
            if (depth == 0) return;
            var neighbours = GetNeighbours(cells);
            var deltaPrice = depth * 0.10f;
            foreach (Cell n in neighbours)
            {
                if (updated.Contains(n)) continue;
                n.GetProduct(productType).Price += deltaPrice;
                updated.Add(n);
            }

            foreach (Cell n in neighbours)
            {
                n.UpdateNearbyPrices(productType, cells, depth - 1, updated);
            }
        }

        public List<Cell> GetNeighbours(Cell[,] cells)
        {
            int row = int.Parse(Id.Split('_')[0]);
            int col = int.Parse(Id.Split('_')[1]);
            List<Cell> neighbours = new List<Cell>();

            for (var dy = -1; dy <= 1; dy++)
                for (var dx = -1; dx <= 1; dx++)
                {
                    if (dx == 0 && dy == 0) continue;
                    if (row + dx < 0 || col + dy < 0) continue;
                    if (row + dx > cells.GetLength(0) - 1 || col + dy > cells.GetLength(1) - 1) continue;

                    Cell neighbour = cells[row + dx, col + dy];
                    neighbours.Add(neighbour);
                }
            return neighbours;
        }
    }

    public class Product
    {
        public ProductType ProductType { get; set; } = ProductType.Lumber;
        public float Price { get; set; } = 30;
    }

    public enum ProductType
    {
        Lumber
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you provide a [mcve]?

Comment: It's kind of difficult for me. I wrote it in godot. You familiar with godot? I can give you a link to full project though: https://github.com/fhgaha/Trains

Comment: Can you provide your code as text in the question that is a complete, runnable example so that we can refactor?

Comment: Give the definition of `stone-thrown-into-a-puddle-like behaviour` which you are expecting to see.

Comment: i added example

Comment: "stone-thrown-into-a-puddle-like behaviour" like a growing mountain

Comment: *what to do with the neighbors of the neighbors?* - don't ask us, tell us. So you want to increase the original cell by 100% of the increment, and then the 8 cells around it by 10% and then the 16 cells around those by 1%, and then the 26 cells around those by 0.1%..? You have to decide these numbers..

Comment: `increase the original cell by 100% of the increment, and then the 8 cells around it by 10% and then the 16 cells around those by 1%, and then the 26 cells around those by 0.1%` - exactly this